# XMLAGG - ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB on CLOB

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, clob

I have the following SQL query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
         prod_no,
         prod_text,
         RTRIM (
            XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, prod_desc, ',').EXTRACT (
                       '//text()') ORDER BY prod_desc).getclobval (),
            ',')
    FROM mytable
   WHERE prod_no = 'XCY'
GROUP BY prod_no,
         prod_text
```

When I execute I am getting

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

**Update 1**

DDL and sample data

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
   prod_no     VARCHAR2 (30 BYTE) NOT NULL,
   prod_text   VARCHAR2 (30 BYTE) NOT NULL,
   prod_desc   CLOB
);

SET DEFINE OFF;

INSERT INTO mytable (prod_no, prod_text, prod_desc)
     VALUES ('XCY', 'DECKS', 'THIS IS TEST');

INSERT INTO mytable (prod_no, prod_text, prod_desc)
     VALUES ('ABC', 'DECKS', 'THIS IS TEST 2');

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Please post the sample table DDL and data.

Comment: @GurV I have included DDL and sample data. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is with `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY`. Oracle doesn't allow these operation on CLOB. You are using `group by`, so you don't need `DISTINCT` anyway.

The below will work, if you don't mind the order of description.

```
SELECT 
         prod_no,
         prod_text,
         RTRIM (
            XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, prod_desc, ',') ).EXTRACT (
                       '//text()').getclobval (),
            ',')
    FROM mytable
   WHERE prod_no = 'XCY'
GROUP BY prod_no,
         prod_text;
```

If you must order by it, you can cast the `CLOB` to `varchar2` and order by it:

```
SELECT
         prod_no,
         prod_text,
         RTRIM (
            XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, prod_desc, ',')
                ORDER BY cast(prod_desc as varchar2(4000))).EXTRACT (
                       '//text()').getclobval (),
            ',')
    FROM mytable
   WHERE prod_no = 'XCY'
GROUP BY prod_no,
         prod_text
```

Comment: @user75ponic - Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated for the insight and help.